# Forcing form to be on the screen

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to force a form to be active and shown?

From another form i am doing:

```
Me.Hide
Form2.Show
```

When this code is run, the Form2 is minimized.

I've also tried:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
```

in the load event, and it still loaded it in minimized mode.

Comment: The window was not minimised - it was just hidden under another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Me.BringToFront(); or you can set the property TopMost true and thus the form will be always on top.

Comment: bringtofront did not work, topmost is good but not exactly what i want

Comment: Have you tried Me.Show(); and Me.BringToFront(); togheter in this order?

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific and explain the flow in which this happens. Are you sure those lines of code are hit by the compiler and still nothing happens ?

Comment: maybe you could explain why TopMost=true is not satisfactory.

Comment: its not satisfactory because then the form does not hide behind other apps if u select to view another ap